# parse.com V1.7.4 ios PFQueryTableViewController reload data

Tags: ios, parse-platform

After upgrading to Parse iOS v1.7.4, `PFQueryTableViewController`                       `loadObjects()` is throwing error. How to reload the table data?

Comment: Please give me more information about it. If you believe this is a solid bug, you should report this to Parse. We can help nothing from the way you describe.

Comment: PFQueryTableViewController had loadObjects() method in previous versions that allowed the table data to get refreshed. However, the current version does not expose that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation from **Parse**, it's in the API documentation so that it will be exposed to the SDK as well. I also check that SDK for you and it does have the `loadObjects()`

```
/*!
 @abstract Clears the table and loads the first page of objects.

 @returns An awaitable task that completes when the reload succeeds
 */
- (BFTask *)loadObjects;
```

Comment: I just download the latest SDK and it does have `loadObjects`

Comment: can u please provide a sample on how to call that? Earlier, I just use to call it as self.loadObjects() which no longer works.

Comment: Again, the information is not sufficient and I could not help you anymore. You should ask yourself why it's not working. What does `self` mean? What's it referring to.

Comment: self refers to instance of PFQueryTableViewController

Answer (score 0):

In the newest Parse SDK, loadObjects is part of Bolts.  That means you'll need to `import Bolts` in order for the function to work.

Answer (score 0):

inserting this line `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>`  in my bridging header class helped me.